# delta modulation

Tags: modulation, quantization

I need to implement some sort of simple delta modulation for my homework.

The test signal is $x(t)=10\sin(20\pi t)+\cos(100\pi t)$, sampled at $f_s=40f_{\tt{max}}$

Block scheme of delta modulator is given as

[image]

where integrator is given as

[image]

and characteristic of 1-bit quantizer is given as

[image]

This is my code where I tried to implement previous logic

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 40 * 50
duration = 0.2

t = np.linspace(0, duration, fs)
test_signal = 10 * np.sin(20 * np.pi * t) + np.cos(100 * np.pi * t)

plt.plot(t, test_signal)
plt.xlabel('t(s)')
plt.ylabel('x(t)')
plt.xticks([0, 5e-2, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

def quantization(element):
  if element > 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return -1

x_m = []
integrator_state = 0

def delta_mod(x_t):

 for i in range(len(x_t)):
     if i == 0:
         x_m.append(quantization(x_t[0]))
         integrator_state = x_m[0]
     else:
         x = x_t[i] - integrator_state
         x_m.append(quantization(x))
         integrator_state = x_m[i]-integrator_state

 delta_mod(test_signal)

 
 plt.plot(t, x_m, drawstyle='steps-pre', label='x_m(t)')
 plt.xlabel('t(s)')
 plt.ylabel('x_m(t)')
 plt.yticks([-4,-2,0,2,4])

 plt.grid(True)

 plt.show()
```

These are plots I get

[image]
[image]

And these are plots that my proffesor got
[image]

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong while trying to implement this logic.

Comment: `x = x_t[i] + integrator_state` Shouldn't this be a subtraction?

Comment: yeah sorry, I was trying different stuff and I forget to change to original code.
I edited the question :)

Comment: I don't use numpy much, but should the linspace be generated as `np.linspace(0, duration, fs*duration)`? Also, `integrator_state = x_m[i]-integrator_state` seems backwards.

Comment: To point out, the integrator block diagram shown does not look correct, the integrator should be the delayed sample added to the next input to the accumulator (an accumulator), not subtracted as shown. The output of the integrator is then subtracted from the input.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it is represented in my lecture presentation but for some reason it is different in the task. However, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

First issue; your `t` is defined incorrectly. It should be: `t = np.linspace(0, duration, int(duration * fs))`

Secondly, you should replace your `delta_mod` function with the following corrected function:

```
def delta_mod(x_t):
    global integrator_state
    x_m.append(quantization(x_t[0]))
    integrator_state = x_m[0] 

    for i in range(1, len(x_t)):
        error = x_t[i] - integrator_state
        q_error = quantization(error)
        x_m.append(q_error)
        integrator_state += q_error
```

In the delta modulation loop, the `integrator_state` is supposed to accumulate the quantized values, but in your code, it's overwritten with just the last quantized value. Ignoring other minor issues and bad coding practices, these are the only significant issues I can see; indeed, it gives me the correct result (as far as I can tell).

[image: x_m(t)]

Comment: Thank you for your help.
The problem I'm having is that if you watch his plot closely, it seems like his signal is not hard clipped on -1 and 1. So I'm wondering if I understood this quantizer characteristic the right way.